# How to detect Windows 10 Anniversary Update on website?

Tags: javascript, windows-10, os-detection

I'd like to detect if a website visitor has the Windows 10 *Anniversary Update* installed. If so I want to offer a link to the app store, if not I'd like to offer a link to my legacy app install package. How can I do that?

Comment: I couldn't see anything in `window.navigator` or user agent string relating to this. I'd say you'd have to go down the java applet / flash / browser plugin route

Comment: @andrew (or anyone) Can you post the user-agent of Edge on Windows 10 Anniversary Update please?

Comment: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.79 Safari/537.36 Edge/14.14393

Comment: So there is no mention of the Anniversary Update in the UA...